# Create SSRS report in SharePoint 2010 integrated mode using SharePointList

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I am new to SSRS and now have a requirement to create reports in SharePoint 2010. I have successfully configured SSRS with SharePoint integrated mode. I am using VS2008 BIDS instance coming with SQL Server 2008 R2. It has three folders "Shared Data Sources", "Shared Datasets" and "Reports". As initial move I created a DataSource of Type 'Microsoft SharePoint Lists' and specified the url of my SharePoint web application. Also created sample reports using wizard by selecting the list and the required fileds, but now i need to create more complicated reports. I need to combine different lists data for the report. How can i build such queries? Also what is needed to be specified in 'Shared Datasets" folder?